# Error : Actual and formal argument lists differ in length?

Tags: java

I'm trying to complete the class which models an shopping cart.

Here's my code:

```
public class ShoppingCart {
    private double price;
    private double subTotal;
    private double cart;

    /**
     * initializing variable named subTotal
     */
    public ShoppingCart() {
        subTotal = 0;
    }

    /**
     * adds this cost to the subtotal for this ShoppingCart
     *
     * @param addPrice Any double value that will be added
     */
    public void add(double addPrice) {
        subTotal = subTotal + addPrice;
    }

    /**
     * subtracts this cost from the subtotal for this ShoppingCart
     *
     * @param subtractPrice Any double value that will be subtracted
     */
    public void remove(double subtractPrice) {
        subTotal = subTotal - subtractPrice;
    }

    /**
     * gets the subtotal for this ShoppingCart
     *
     * @param totalCost Any double value that will be the total amount
     * @return the cost of things in ShoppingCart
     */
    public double getSubtotal(double totalCost) {
        totalCost = subTotal;
        return subTotal;
    }
}


public class ShoppingCartTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart();
        cart.add(10.25);
        cart.add(1.75);
        cart.add(5.50);
        System.out.println(cart.getSubtotal());
        System.out.println("Expected: 17.5");
        cart.remove(5.50);
        cart.add(3);
        System.out.println(cart.getSubtotal());
        System.out.println("Expected: 15.0");
    }
}
```

From `System.out.println(cart.getSubtotal());` I got an error which says that *actual and formal argument lists differ in length*.

Comment: That's only because your actual and formal argument lists differ in length. Seriously though, why do you have your `getSubtotal` function accept an argument that does nothing? Get rid of it, and your call will work.

Comment: sure, just update your method as: `public double getSubtotal() { return subTotal; }` and compiler will be satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because the method requires a double to be passed in, but you are calling it with no parameters.

You can change your getSubtotal method to look like this and it will simply return the value of your subtotal variable after the additions:

```
public double getSubtotal() {
    return subTotal;
}
```

That should give you your desired results!

Comment: Thank you so much! you are a life saver:)